# Is it possible to predict parking behaviour based on dataset of car parking event

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, data-mining, logistic-regression

We have

```
EventDate
EventTime
Latitude
Longitude
EventDuration
user ID
```

details for many users for car parking event.

**Is it possble to identify top 5 meaningful “parking behaviors” and calculate their popularity in the user base.?**

I dont want hard-core solution. Just reference to some helping algorithm or article would be much appreciable.

Comment: What's a parking behaviour?

Comment: ... and what is 'meaningful'?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to derive behaviors such as "parking to go for shopping in the supermarket", "overnight parking", "5 minutes parking to pick up someone" etc.

For supervised learning, you can try kNN.

For unsupervised learning you can try k-means clustering and HSMM (hidden semi markov models).

User IDs are irrelevant for the task. latitude and longitude are useful only for unsupervised learning tasks because for supervised learning you would need to tag in some way groups or pairs of (lat,long) and tag them in order to point to supermarking car parks etc.

If I misunderstood something because the question is broad, feel free to explain in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Here we have given car parking events with given fields, we want to identify useful behavious of parking so that it can be managed well. As we have 100k of user data, I guess using supervised leaning can help better.

Comment: Supervised learning is much more appreciated in your case. Consider an extra preprocessing step with the lat,long because it is going to be very helpful. ps: upvote please if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: I dont have enough point to upvote.I wanted it too. I need 15 points and I have 12 only. : )

Comment: I upvoted you so no you can :). Sorry I thought I have done it before

Comment: can you please give your email, I would like to discuss this more?